# VirtualBox does not show my VM when launched from the menu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox on Ubuntu 11.04. I launched it from the console and added a virtual Windows XP. Everything was working okay, but when I added VirtualBox as a shortcut to my menu it opens without this Windows virtual machine.

Why is this and how would I change the shortcut so I can see my VM?

Comment: How did you start it from the console *exactly*? Which commands did you type? Were you logged in as another user when you did so?

Comment: I have just type `virtualbox`

Comment: Quick test. When you open a fresh new terminal and enter `sudo virtualbox`, do you see your VM there? Now, if you enter just `virtualbox`, are they gone now?

Comment: Yest VM is there when I open new terminal

Comment: yes XP is there

Answer (score 2):

You configured your VirtualBox installation as the wrong user, i.e. `root`. You were probably starting VirtualBox with `sudo virtualbox` and therefore your whole configuration was written to `/root/.VirtualBox` instead of `/home/your-username/.VirtualBox`.

---

- First, stop all instances of VirtualBox.
- According to [VirtualBox 4.0 documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html), you should find your VM in `root`'s home folder, which we'll open with this command:

  ```
  gksudo nautilus /root/VirtualBox\ VMs &
  ```
- Here, you should see a directory for the Windows VM. Take that directory, and copy it to `/home/your-username/VirtualBox VMs`. Close the Nautilus window.
- Then, take ownership of this folder again. Might not be necessary, but doesn't hurt.

  ```
  sudo chown -R your-username /home/your-username/VirtualBox\ VMs/
  ```
- Now, restart VirtualBox over the normal menu shortcut or by running `virtualbox` from the Terminal. Are you able see your VM now?

Comment: It didn't help, still I cant see my XP

Comment: Does your `/home/your-username/VirtualBox VMs` folder now contain the Windows machine? Are you the owner of said folder (by looking at its permissions)? You could also try to set up a new VM and choose the `.vdi` file that is now in your home folder as the disk.

Comment: I tried to export from root and import on my acount by there was some errors, so I decied to reinstall XP on this acount. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you install the VM as an user different from the one you used to launch VirtualBox.
This happened to me when I had used vagrant to create my VMs as user X, and then tried to check the VM installation status on VirtualBox as user Y.